# is there an elegant way to perform arithmetic on tuples (eg. pairs) in c++?

Tags: c++

The title pretty much says it all.  I would like to do:

```
std::pair<int,int> a(2,1), b(1,1), c(0,0);
c=a-b;
```

and get c=(1,0).   If it involves defining a new class and doing operator overloading that's ok I suppose, I'd still be interested in seeing the most elegant way to do that, but it would be even better, imo, if there was a non-boost, non-new-class-definition solution.  Thanks!  -Mark

Comment: Consider using a dedicated vector class (not the container but like a coordinate)

Comment: Some reasoning why arithmetics with tuples is not defined in cpp and an implementation can be found here: https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/384563/arithmetic-tuple

Comment: thanks Neil & Tobias - both your comments make sense.  I'm generally a C++ programmer, but in the past year I've gotten used to the fast-and-loose style of javascript.  I guess I was hoping there was something I was just missing in the std library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[std::valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) is designed to support numerical computation on vectors (that is, ordered sequences of numbers).

```
std::valarray<int> a {2, 1}, b {1, 1}, c;
c = a - b;
```

You can access its elements like you would access those of `std::vector`, *i.e.*, with the subscripting operator `[]`.

Comment: Should probably disambiguate that use of the word "vectors" ;)

Comment: I did not know about the existence of std::valarrays - thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You could always write your own operators:

```
std::pair<int, int> operator+(const std::pair<int, int>& a, 
    const std::pair<int, int>& b)
{
    return std::make_pair(a.first + b.first, a.second + b.second);
}

// other operators here

std::pair<int,int> a(2,1), b(1,1);
auto c = a + b; // yields (3,2)
```

Can even generalize out to arbitrary tuples with some help from integer sequences (there's lots of places to lookup how to do this):

```
template <size_t I, typename... T>
typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<T...>>::type
addi(const std::tuple<T...>&a, const std::tuple<T...>&b)
{
    return std::get<I>(a) + std::get<I>(b);
}

template <size_t... I, typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> add(sequence<I...>, const std::tuple<T...>&a, const std::tuple<T...>&b)
{
    return std::make_tuple(addi<I>(a,b)...);
}


template <typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> operator+(const std::tuple<T...>& a, const std::tuple<T...>& b)
{
    return add(typename gen_sequence<sizeof...(T)>::type{}, a, b); 
}


std::tuple<int, int, int> ta{1, 1, 2};
std::tuple<int, int, int> tb{2, 2, 2};

auto tc = ta + tb; // yields <3, 3, 4>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a new class, you can define global free function templates like the this:

```
template<typename T>
std::pair<T,T> operator - (const std::pair<T,T> & lhs, const std::pair<T,T> & rhs)
{
    return std::pair<T,T>(lhs.first - rhs.first, lhs.second - rhs.second);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    (void)argc; (void)argv;

    std::pair<int,int> a(2,1), b(1,1), c(0,0);
    c=a-b;
    return 0;
}
```